# Are tags retained on Time Machine backups and in Trash?

Tags: macos, time-machine, trash, finder-tag

When viewing by **tags** in Finder I get no results from Time Machine or Trash.  Are tags not retained by Time Machine or Trash?  What about external disks?  Spotlight is configured to index everything, no exceptions.

Comment: It's my understanding that spotlight won't index a TM backup, as it's a special kind of folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spotlight doesn't index Time Machine backups or the Trash.  It does do external disks but certain conditions have to be met for it to do them.